# Background Image Cover Without Width Getting Wider If Page Is Too Long

Tags: css

Is there a way of having a background image getting wider whenever a page is too long.
ps. i know how to make a one fill the page, that was what i was using

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 background-size:cover;
```

To make the background image literally stretch to fill the element or

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```

To make the image 'tile', however I'd expect neither to look very good if the original image is small and the containing image is very large.

A working example [can be found on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually did this by accident on one of my websites. Here was my CSS for the `div` that had the image:

```
background: url("image.jpg") no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
```

Note that this will make the image resize so that the background image will **always** have the right scale between height and width, by centering it whether or not the screen is too wide or too tall. Hope this helped you!